# Why couldn't I use the mean() function to a CSV file?

Tags: r, csv, mean

I want to use the mean() function to a numerical CSV file.

The code is very simple.

```
data <- read.csv("12.csv")
mean(data)
```

```
    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9
1 10.01 10.13 10.09 10.08 10.12 10.16 10.15 10.21 10.12
```

However, R studio informs me of a warning message that "In mean.default(data) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

But sd() function and sum() function are available.

How can I do to apply the mean() function to my CSV file??

If someone has any idea, I will very appreciate.

Comment: because `mean` expects a vector and not a dataframe. See `?mean`

Comment: do you need `colMeans(data)`?

Comment: Ohhh~~ I got it!! 
I use the ```colMeans(data)``` to transform my data. 
After that, I can use the mean() function to the data.
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dput()` to provide your data since we do not have the csv file:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(X1 = 10.01, X2 = 10.13, X3 = 10.09, X4 = 10.08, 
    X5 = 10.12, X6 = 10.16, X7 = 10.15, X8 = 10.21, X9 = 10.12),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

The `mean` function works on vectors, not data frames (lists). Do you want the mean of the row?

```
rowMeans(data)
       1 
10.11889
```

Do you have more than one row and you want the mean of all the values in all of the rows? For example we can stack your row of data to make three rows:

```
mean(unlist(rbind(data, data, data)))
[1] 10.11889
```

The `unlist()` function converts the data frame to a simple string of values. This only works if all of the columns are numeric. Alternatively you can take the mean of the row means:

```
mean(rowMeans(rbind(data, data, data)))
[1] 10.11889
```